# Facing issue with okhttp3 library of version 3.1.2 for azure calls

Tags: java, azure, okhttp

I'm facing issue with *okhttp3* library of version 3.1.2 for Azure calls for below code

```
 //create proxy authenticator object    
Authenticator proxyAuthenticator = new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Request authenticate(okhttp3.Route route, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
        String credential = Credentials.basic("user", "password");
        return response.request().newBuilder().header("Proxy-Authorization", credential).build();
    }
};

OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
clientBuilder.connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
clientBuilder.writeTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
clientBuilder.readTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
clientBuilder.proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.valueOf("HTTP"), new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)));
clientBuilder.proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator);

Retrofit.Builder retroBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder();
retroBuilder.client(clientBuilder.build());
ResourceManagementClient armClient = new ResourceManagementClientImpl(baseURL, appTokenCreds,
        clientBuilder, retroBuilder);
armClient.setLongRunningOperationRetryTimeout(100000);
armClient.setSubscriptionId(System.getenv(subscriptionId));
System.out.println("API version :" + armClient.getApiVersion());
try {
    armClient.setSubscriptionId(subscriptionId);
    ServiceResponse<List<Provider>> result = armClient.getProvidersOperations().list(null);
} catch (AzureResourceManagerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error I got:

```
 Exception
    HTTP
    API version :2015-11-01
    hi
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

 )
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on null
        at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:199)
        at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.createTunnel(RealConnection.java:251)
        at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:175)
        at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:148)
        at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:111)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
        at com.microsoft.rest.UserAgentInterceptor.intercept(UserAgentInterceptor.java:58)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
        at com.microsoft.rest.retry.RetryHandler.intercept(RetryHandler.java:69)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
        at com.microsoft.rest.credentials.TokenCredentialsInterceptor.sendRequestWithAuthorization(TokenCredentialsInterceptor.java:49)
        at com.microsoft.rest.credentials.TokenCredentialsInterceptor.intercept(TokenCredentialsInterceptor.java:37)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
        at com.microsoft.azure.CustomHeaderInterceptor.intercept(CustomHeaderInterceptor.java:133)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:177)
        at com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.ProvidersOperationsImpl.list(ProvidersOperationsImpl.java:240)
        at com.bmc.cloud.provider.azureconnect.arm.TestARM.getLocations(TestARM.java:201)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:184)
        ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception "Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder", it seems that missing some jar library files for logger implementation in the classpath for your project, for example, such as `log4j` & `slf4j-log4j`. Please try to add these jar files into the project and note the different version `1.2` or `2.2` for `log4j` & `slf4j-log4j`.

Meanwhile, I discovered some possible issues in your code, please see below.

1. According to the the constructor [`ResourceManagementClientImpl(String baseUrl, ServiceClientCredentials credentials, OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder, Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder)`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/1.0.0-beta1/azure-mgmt-resources/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/resources/ResourceManagementClientImpl.java#L254) in your code, it seems that you are using the version `1.0.0-beta1` of Azure SDK for Java, because the constructor is only for this version.

So I recommend that using a stable version like `0.9` is better than beta verion, please see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-mgmt-resources.

2. According to the example [`VMCreateGuide.java`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/1.0.0-beta1/examples/VMCreateGuide/src/main/java/VMCreateGuide.java) for version `1.0.0-beta1`,  I discovered the codes `new Authenticator()` and `Credentials.basic("user", "password")` is not suitable for calling ARM APIs, or it seems to be set http client with credentials via a proxy server to do call Azure APIs.

So if you want to call Azure with Resource Manager via porxy server, the code seems to be missing ARM authentication. If not, I think you need to use the correct class `ApplicationTokenCredentials`& `UserTokenCredentials` in of the package [`com.microsoft.azure.credentials`](https://github.com/Azure/autorest-clientruntime-for-java/tree/master/azure-client-authentication/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/credentials) to authenticate for ARM like doing in the sample `VMCreateGuide.java`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response !!!! I will follow your suggestions and see if that helps